# Angular 7 binding dropdowns

Tags: angular, ngmodel

How to synchronize array content and display?

My purpose: "groupeBeatles" is my reference array and "nom" / "prenom" displayed controls must always comply with this array. This callback is meant for that :

```js
synchroMembre($event) {
    const prenom: string = this.groupeBeatles.filter(membre => {
        membre.nom = this.nomCourant;
    })[0].prenom;
    console.log('******* prenomCourant - prenom *************', this.prenomCourant, ' - ', prenom);
    this.prenomCourant = prenom;
}
```

For example, if I attribute to "Lennon" the first name "Paul", he must correct himself in "John". It's not the case!

What goes wrong in my example? (See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evhyxm))

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to align the names with each other based on the selection,

What you wrongly implemented is the filter function,

Your filter function should look like this,

```
 const newName: string = this.groupeBeatles.filter(membre => membre.prenom === $value)[0].nom;       
    this.nomCourant=newName;
```

you are actually assigning the values inside filter that is wrong, filter is to filter-out the values, so you need to return the true or false values. 
[recommended read to understand the filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

If you want apply to both you can do something like this

```
  synchroMembre($value, typeChange) {
    if (typeChange === 'pren') {
      const newName: string = this.groupeBeatles.filter(membre => membre.prenom === $value)[0].nom;
      this.nomCourant = newName;
    } else {
      const newName: string = this.groupeBeatles.filter(membre => membre.nom === $value)[0].prenom;
      this.prenomCourant = newName;
    }

  }
```

and pass the values

```
<form #monForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="prenom">Prénom</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="prenom" [ngModel]="prenomCourant" (ngModelChange)="synchroMembre($event,'pren')" required name="prenom">
          <option *ngFor="let pren of prenoms" [value]="pren">{{ pren }}</option>
        </select>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nom">Nom</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="nom" [(ngModel)]="nomCourant" (ngModelChange)="synchroMembre($event,'nom')" required name="nom">
          <option *ngFor="let nom of noms" [value]="nom">{{nom}}</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvpzck)

Comment: Thanks for your correction:I mistakenly typed '=' instead of '===' but it still does not work

Comment: @Caplande check my edit and demo, you will get an idea, you are also getting the values incorrectly

Comment: No, it's not my question. In my example, I'm just trying to get the "prenom" back to its good value when I change it with a wrong "prenom".

For example:
Considering the two "nom" and "prenom" controls, starting from the "nom" "Lennon" if I change "prenom" to "Paul" this one must go back to "John" (and this is not the case).

NOTA: I have only wired control "prenom" for that test.

Comment: No, consider "nom" set to value "Lennon".
If I change "prenom" to "Paul", I want it comes back to "John"

Comment: I just understood that what I'm doing here leads to an endless loop. Indeed, if I change again "prenom" inside the callback, it triggers the same callback again. How then to treat the question?

Comment: @Caplande you need to fix the requirement, yes, what you are asking is an endless loop. I think changing both the things will do the trick as I posted in answer. or you can use the onchange event of the select, something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cuiget?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts but in this case you can only bind one way.

Comment: @Caplande But I suggest let user choose the name and then you can change other dropdown, as posted in my answer.